# Select photos taken every five minutes

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-explorer

I have, on a shared drive, several folders containing thousands of photographs. I'd like to create new folders containing only those photographs taken every five minutes, i.e., those with "Date Modified" ending in ". . . :00 AM" or ". . . :05 AM" (or PM). Is there a way I, with very little knowledge about command prompt etc., can do this?

In the linked screenshot, I've highlighted the files I'd like to move to a new folder.

Thanks!

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOzzj.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Edit you question with more detail -- example paths, etc. Posing a basic answer that doesn't deal with destination folder creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **PowerShell**, it would work like this:

1. Get picture files using [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)

   - `gci -Path .$Source -FIlter *.raw -Recurse`
2. Filter by LastWriteTime using [Where-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)

   - `Where { $_.LastWriteTime.Minute % 5 -eq 0 }`
3. Copy to $Destination using [Copy-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item)

   - `copy -Destination $Dest`

These operations can be combined into a single [pipeline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines):

```
$Source = 'c:\Source'
$Dest = 'd:\dest'

gci -path $source -filter *.raw -recurse |
    where { $_.LastWriteTime.Minute % 5 -eq 0 } |
        copy -Destination $Dest -WhatIf
```

Start playing with that code one lilne at a time:

1. Make sure `gci ...` spits out lots of picutre files. ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to halt )
2. Add the pipe (`|`) and `where ....` cmdlet and verify it's returning the files you want.
3. Add `Copy ...` with the `-WhatIf` parameter to verify destination.
4. Remove `-WhatIf` to actually copy files.

Comment: Thank you. This works well EXCEPT that the where cmdlet returns all files, not just every five minutes.

Comment: Sorry, `where` variable should be `$_` rather than `$file`. Will edit answer to correct....

Comment: I had it right in the step-by-step, but screwed up the code block! --- apologies